# Error with netCDF4 import in python

Tags: python, mpi, undefined-symbol

I get the following error when I try to use netcdf4 in python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
from netCDF4 import Dataset
ImportError: /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/netCDF4.so: undefined symbol:       MPI_File_get_atomicity
```

I tried already to recompile mpich2 but this didn't help.
Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Cheers,
Sven

Comment: Did you try rebuilding the netCDF4 library after rebuilding mpich2?

Comment: Daer James,
yes, I tried this too but still getting the same error message.

Comment: I just do it like this:
    python setup.py build && python setup.py install

Comment: Without knowing more about your system, environment, versions etc, it would be hard to reproduce the error you're seeing because if I tried to install netCDF4 I'd likely succeed. Have you tried the latest version(s)?

Comment: Ok, now I solved this error. There was an older version of the netCDF4.so on my system by which I replaced /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/netCDF4.so and then it worked.

Comment: Could you help clarify the answer a bit in case anyone else runs into a similar problem as you? :)

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of questions are always hard to answer and are usually very specific.

In this case:

- Upgrade netCDF4 library
- Recompile